# How to Create Table Name That Contains Last Month in Suffix

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create a table with the last month's name as part of the table name.
If the current month is February then I would want the table name to look like this: `table_name_jan18`

The statement I have so far looks like this:

```
create table abc_'||'trunc(SYSDATE,'mm')-1';
```

Comment: Probably depends on how you are going to execute the statement. Regardless of that you need to declare what the table looks like.

Comment: Usually it is a poor design to name table like that. By this all your queries and PL/SQL code have to be dynamic as well. Better look for a design without such prefix. Maybe partitioning would be a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare
  l_cmd clob;
begin
  l_cmd := 'create table abc_'|| to_char(add_months(SYSDATE,-1), 'MONDD') || ' (c1 number)';
  execute immediate l_cmd;
end;
/

SQL> select table_name from user_tables where table_name like 'ABC%';

TABLE_NAME
----------
ABC_JAN13


SQL> desc abc_jan13
 Name  Null?    Type
 ----- -------- -------
 C1             NUMBER
```

Comment: I assume it should be rather `to_char(add_months(SYSDATE,-1), 'MONYY')`, i.e. `JAN18` for January 2018. Note, result of `to_char(..., 'MON')` depends on current user `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` setting.